# Finding the maximum sequence in a given range - Spark/Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am practicing a problem with Spark using Scala and I have a football league table with columns (`teamname, lastgame, nextgame, dateoflastgame, dateofnextgame`)

I am trying to run a query on the data where I can determine the longest run a team will go without playing the same team twice. I. E. For a team (`CHL, MNU, ARS, 01/01/2020,08/01/2020`)

There are multiple entries for CHL across the season having all this data, I am trying to find the longest run they would have without coming across a certain team e. g. MCU.

For example a run would look like of next games, `MCU-BHA-LIV-WHU-TOT-MCU` would be a run of 4 games.

I have been using spark sql and thinking querying against nextgame `where teamname='mnu'` but I'm quite puzzled how I would count these values and return the maximum run of games without playing MCU. Furthermore, I would like to do this operation against all the teams in the league to get a list of the longest runs without playing MCU.

Any thoughts where I could start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions to the rescue.

```
val df = Seq(
    ("CHL", "MCU", "2020-01-01"),
    ("CHL", "BHA", "2020-01-02"),
    ("CHL", "LIV", "2020-01-03"),
    ("CHL", "WHU", "2020-01-04"),
    ("CHL", "TOT", "2020-01-05"),
    ("CHL", "MCU", "2020-01-06")
).toDF("teamname", "nextgame", "dateofnextgame")

val w = Window.partitionBy($"teamname")

df.withColumn("seq", row_number().over(w.orderBy($"dateofnextgame"))).
  withColumn("max", count(lit(1)).over(w)).
  filter($"nextgame" === "MCU").
  withColumn("next_seq", coalesce(lead($"seq" - 1, 1).over(w.orderBy($"seq")), lit($"max"))).
  withColumn("streak", $"next_seq" - $"seq").
  groupBy($"teamname").
  agg(max($"streak").as("max_streak")).
  show

+--------+----------+
|teamname|max_streak|
+--------+----------+
|     CHL|         4|
+--------+----------+
```

In the end it's pretty simple, you just assign a sequence number to games and the longest run is maximum difference between seq of current and next game against MCU.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not came across the '$' operation, what exactly does this do and how do I import it? Currently, I have '$ is not a member of string context'. Many thanks.

Comment: `$"name"` converts string `"name"` into a `Column`. You need to run `import spark.implicits._` to have it available. -> [docs](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-SparkSession-implicits.html)

Comment: So this partially works. It is creating something but I have used
 ' df = spark.sql(("SELECT teamname,lastgame,nextgame,dateofnextgame FROM complete_data ORDER BY teamname, dateofnextgame" ' and not the seq you have used because I have a large datafile. I have also specified a specific date range between January and March.

When I run it, it does produce some numbers but there are a lot of null answers because a team hasn't played MCU in the time frame, so has rendered it null rather than say 6. Any ideas on small modifications I could make to ensure a value even if they never play MCU.

Comment: If a team hasn't played against MCU at all, the longest run is simply the number of games, right?

Comment: Yes this is the case